# CSS media query display-mode: fullscreen does not work on safari

Tags: javascript, css, safari, fullscreen

CSS media query display-mode:fullscreen does not work on safari (the css inside the media query never gets applied). Current safari version: Version 14.1.

```
@media all and (display-mode: fullscreen) {
...
}
```

Full example here: https://jsfiddle.net/gnbcv6em/3/
It works on chrome but not safari. I've tried triggering fullscreen with the browser's fullscreen keyboard shortcut or by triggering it manually with js, but neither works on safari.

Also, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/display-mode shows that safari supports it.

Perhaps someone has come across this issue and can help?

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Also having the same issue here. Must be a fix for this...

Answer (score 0):

Faced with the same issue. Solved by this:

```
body:-webkit-full-screen .selector {
  display: none;
}
```

And SCSS version (if you have nested selectors):

```scss
@at-root body:-webkit-full-screen & {
  display: none;
}
```

At this moment Safari [doesn't support](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_selectors_fullscreen) `:fullscreen` selector, so need to use `:-webkit-full-screen`.